# Converting numbers/string to time - PROLOG

Tags: prolog, scheduling

I am a beginner in prolog and was wondering if there was an easy way to convert numbers to time, for comparison.

For example:
The below two lists show bus name, capacity, time it arrives at city, time it departs city.
bus_info(bus1,150, 12:30, 14:30).
bus_info(bus2, 200, 16:00, 18:00).

passenger_info(mike, 21, 17:30). -shows name, age, and time available

I want to check which bus Mike can catch. The answer is bus 2, but how do I calculate this in prolog?

Answer (score 2):

You're just comparing times for a given day so you don't need to convert the numbers to any kind of system time encoding. You only need, say "minutes past midnight" or something like that. For example, `12:30` would be `(12*60)+30` minutes past midnight. And you can use that as your comparison units for a daily schedule.

To capture your hours and minutes to do this calculation, if you were to "ask" in Prolog:

```
bus_info(Bus, Num, StartHH:StartMM, EndHH:EndMM).
```

You would get two results:

```
Bus = bus1
Num = 150
StartHH = 12
StartMM = 30
EndHH = 14
EndHH = 30
```

And

```
Bus = bus2
Num = 200
StartHH = 16
StartMM = 0
EndHH = 18
EndMM = 0
```

To assign a numeric value of an expression in Prolog, you need the `is` predicate. For example:

```
StartTime is (StartHH * 60) + StartMM.
```

That basic information should get you started if you've learned how Prolog predicates basically work.

Comment: I might worry because this operator is used by some Prologs (notably SWI) as the module namespace resolution operator. But this seems to work out of the box in SWI and GNU, so maybe I'm worrying for no reason…